# Buttons work, ImageButtons do NOT

Tags: java, android, button, imagebutton

I have searched for a lot of references on ImageButton for Android. And did exactly the same, but it did not seem to work. The strange part, it worked when I used 'Button' only. 
Have I missed out some important part?

Can anyone help me with my problem please?
I have listed down my code below.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Button connectBtn = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.connectBtn); //<<<=== THIS WORKS
    ImageButton connectBtn = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.connectBtn); // <<<=== THIS NOT
    ImageButton getPy = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.getFilePy); // <<<=== THIS NOT
    ImageButton runPy = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.runPy); // <<<=== THIS NOT

    connectBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mySetConfig();
        }
    });

    getPy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showFileChooser();
        }
    });
    runPy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pythonButton();
        }
    });
}
```

XML:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/connectBtn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_1" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/getPy"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_2" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/runPy"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_3" />

 <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/FrameLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</FrameLayout>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/app_status"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:singleLine="false" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you in advance for your kind heart.

Comment: do you have imagebutton in your xml layout? show us your xml layout

Comment: Post your XML too, please

Comment: post also your activity xml please

Comment: everything looks fine to me. Kindly post your xml

Comment: Also, define "it did not seem to work"

Comment: i guess you are casting button to ImageButton.

Comment: I have always have problems with ImageButton. I am using normal ImageView instead. You can set onClickListener to every view tough.

Comment: the only error i can spot is  `ImageButton getPy = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.getPy)` not this     `ImageButton getPy = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.getFilePy)`

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your project? You may have made changes that Eclipse didn't recognize. Project --> Clean

Comment: how about remove `@Override`

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to put the click Listener to an ImageButton:

```
    ImageButton connectBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.connectBtn);

    connectBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                      mySetConfig();

        }

    });
```

Here's a nice [tut](http://custom-android-dn.blogspot.com/2012/12/fromdeveloper.html) for you.
And please remove the "this" word from herE:

ImageButton connectBtn = (ImageButton)**this**.findViewById(R.id.connectBtn);  <<<=== THIS NOT

Comment: Here are two more tuts: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/imagebutton/android-imagebutton-example/ and http://vimaltuts.com/android-tutorial-for-beginners/android-custom-button .

Comment: this refers to activity context `this` is not a problem